# Токенизация с RegexpTokenizer: найти русские слова

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, естественный-язык

Мне нужно разбить текст по словам, при этом, чтобы исключились все слова, кроме русских, и все знаки препинания. `wordpunct_tokenize` этого сделать не позволяет. Кажется, это можно сделать с помощью `RegexpTokenizer`, задав ему регулярное выражение. 
Подскажите, с помощью какого регулярного выражения можно это сделать или посоветуйте другие токенайзеры, которые могут дать то, что мне нужно.

Comment: «Салтыков-Щедрин»—это одно слово или два? Вам нужен пример, используя nltk? (Поставьте данные с русским языком, используя `nltk.download()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
for word in re.findall(r'[А-Яа-я]+', 'one, два, три, four', re.U):
    print(word)
```

Comment: Букву ё/Ё забыли.

Comment: 1- Это неверно: не все русские буквы охвачены. 2- Если вы для Питона 3 пример кода приводите, то стоит это явно упомянуть, если вопрос не имеет соответствующей метки.  Также стоит упомянуть Юникод, проблемы нормализации 3- в общем случае, слова не обязаны содержать только буквы.

Comment: В любом случае понадобится словарик исключений для слов содержащих дефис и сокращений с пробелами и точками: "_кто-то_", "_до н. э._", "_и т. д._".